# Why are the answers out of order now?

Tags: support, answers, upvotes, sorting

The answers on Stack Overflow used to be ordered by the following rule:

> Accepted answer first followed by non-accepted answers in decreasing order of score.

However, now it seems to use the time of answer to order the answers.

For instance in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364819/why-do-we-needed-category-when-we-can-use-a-subclass-and-why-we-needed-blocks-w/24364957?noredirect=1#comment37676525_24364957), my answer was first and has the highest score but appears (for me) at the bottom of the list of answers.

Comment: There are sorting tabs at the top of the answers section, you probably selected one you're not used to.

Comment: You picked a **different** sort order, sorting by *activity*. Only sorting by votes or by oldest would put your post at the top.

Comment: thanks for asking, I can't even recall ever having clicked on it but only today noticed something was different with the order of the answers

Comment: Came here with the same question.... Maybe a signal that the UI could be cleaned up in this respect?

Comment: Many years later and still the same issue! I also have no memory of ever clicking on it and didn't notice it's existence. Is there any data on user settings here? Seems like an issue that can break a user experience, but probably is never used.

Comment: On MSE: [Answers no longer sorted by score/votes](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/191493/289905).

Comment: how to permantly set to highest score? I change it on any question but whenever I leave and come back its sorted by newest first, with all the espam answers recently its quite annoying

Comment: @Olli it should save your preference. When I set it it is set permanently so perhaps it's an issue with cookies on your computer or something?

Comment: hmm, @Fogmeister I have this on both my laptop and desktop. I'll try clearing cookies on both

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Your answer is sorted first *provided you pick the right sort order*:

> [image: answers with tab to alter voting order circled]

If you sorted by *oldest* yours would be listed first as well. When sorting by *active* instead, your post is sorted last.

Your sort preference is persisted; if you picked a different sort order on a different question, then until you change the setting, all question pages will use that sort order.

This applies to just most 'tab' options on the site; the big exception I can think of is the search results (which sort by relevancy instead). Keep that in mind when results are unexpected, like no questions for a popular tab because you picked the 'featured' tab while there are no bountied questions for that tag at that time.

If you have the [keyboard shortcuts preference enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current), it'll be relatively easy to accidentally change the sort order; all it takes is typing <kbd>O</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> to switch to *Active* or *Oldest* sort order, respectively. This is especially easy to miss if you disabled the <kbd>H</kbd> automatic help dialog that appears after typing <kbd>O</kbd>. Type in <kbd>O</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> to go back to sorting by votes.

Comment: Worth noting, the sorts on the _main_ page have the same 'sticky' behavior (I just deleted my answer that duplicated this one)

Comment: @TimPost: heh, added a short paragraph on this applying to almost all tab options. :-)

Comment: This is very poor UX. I have no idea why the other sort orders exist, so it never would have occurred to me that pressing some keys would have silently changed to one of them (permanently!). Thank goodness for this question.

Comment: @RadonRosborough: the keyboard shortcuts need to be enabled explicitly, and include context-sensitive help. When you have them enabled and you use `?`, you get a menu of options including *`O`: order answers by ...*. When you first start using them, *autohelp* is also enabled, which pops up a menu the moment you use the `O` key, showing you what next key is needed to sort the answers. I'm not sure how much better the UI for a feature that's meant to *avoid having to use the GUI* can be here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters is it just me or has the `O` shortcut disappeared? I can't find it in the help list and when pressing `O` nothing happens

Comment: @JensV: no, I had noticed it has been removed recently, too.

Comment: Just going to have to agree with others... I even tried to find sorting options on the page and couldn't... that missing <hr/> makes a huge difference to the usability for me.

Comment: Wth happened to the `O` shortcut?  Please bring it back