# Low voted, non-accepted answer on top

Tags: support

What's with this low voted, non-accepted answer given 6 years later being on top with only 4 votes?

[R function for testing if a vector contains a given element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169248/r-function-for-testing-if-a-vector-contains-a-given-element)

Only 4 votes for an answer on a 7 year-old question with much better answers (not just in my opinion but validated by votes), one of which was accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261338/why-are-the-answers-out-of-order-now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have had your **sorting criteria** as `active` ... change it to `oldest` or `votes`

- As the user's post was the most recent post with activity, it got the top position:

[image]

---

- When **sorting criteria** as `oldest`:

[image]

---

- When **sorting criteria** as `votes`:

[image]

Comment: OK. I did see it as "active" which is not exactly a synonym in my mind for "newest" but if that's the way SO is set up then I suppose you have answered my question. Is that choice something that persists from prior viewing.

Comment: yes, it's not exactly newest...if any user edits his or her question the, it becomes the top most post in `active` sorting method

Comment: yes its a choice that persists from prior viewing @42-