# Why isn't there a way/option to sort on deleted questions saved from the "favorites" tab in the profile area?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, bookmarks, sorting

Note: This question is for members with 10k reputation (or more) and ♦ moderators. These questions were starred/favorited at the time the question was made viewable by all, as per the favorites tab in the profile area.

I was going over questions that I favorited over time (where some ended up being deleted), only to return to them at a later date and wonder why there isn't an option to sort on deleted questions.

I did find this post on meta:

- [Why are the answers out of order now?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261338/why-are-the-answers-out-of-order-now)

Using the "sorting by votes" works to a certain extent, but that still shows me a few questions here and there (on pagefulls) that are not deleted and I also have to go to the very last page(s) in order to see them.

Is there a reason why that option isn't available? I didn't find anything on the subject, which is why I am asking.

It would be handy to have and to start unfavoriting them all (or most), even though they would need to be unstarred one by one, where a "check all" option would definitely be a time-saver.

Comment: AFAIK, deletion updates the active time.

Comment: @Braiam I don't understand what you mean sorry. How would/can deleted questions be sorted so they're together in order for them to either be unfavorited or seen?

Comment: One would expect that deleted question hasn't been active in a long time, so you could order by active and go towards the end of the list to search them. But AFAIK, deletion updates the active time.

Comment: @Braiam I just tried sorting by activity and the deleted posts are not bunched together. As I mentioned in my question, sorting by votes seems to work best, but it still shows a few questions that are not deleted. My question is about sorting by deleted questions, which I find would be beneficial for deletion purposes mostly.

Comment: wait... how are you seeing deleted questions that you favorited? i mean, unless they're your questions of course.

Comment: @KevinB I can see deleted questions from other posters. Have you not favorited/starred any that may have been deleted?

Comment: @Fred-ii- infavorites only returns questions, and deleted:yes only returns posts that are yours. So if the favorited question is not yours and is deleted, you shouldn't be able to see it in that result list. What search criteria are you using to make this work?

Comment: @KevinB Well sure I can :-) Here, see this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/40130662/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/44113773/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/33894570/ just to name a few that I starred a long time ago; I have a lot of these. You can see them and you can also favorite/unfavorite it; go ahead and try it, you have enough rep for it. You'll also see 1's under the stars or more.

Comment: from the SO Search bar? or from the favorites tab in your profile

Comment: @KevinB as per my title: *"on deleted questions saved from “favorites”?"*. I guess I should edit my question.

Comment: hmm... that's still unclear to me. favorites in profile? favorites in browser?

Comment: Ah, ok, i understand now. yeah, that's not possible currently, i wish it were possible to search these using the search tools available so that we could then filter it how we want. for example, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3Amine+deleted%3Ayes plus a quantifier that tells it to search the answers of the favorites that match, etc

Comment: @KevinB well, it's not really about "searching" per se, but more about sorting on deleted, so that I can unstar/unfavorite them faster, rather than going over each and every pagination, only to find 2 or 3 on one page, then 3-5 on another, possibly none on a few subsequent pages etc.

Comment: well, if you keep up with it you could use activity. Theoretically if anything is deleted once you go through and delete all the existing ones, it'l show up higher in the activity sort. but so will anything else with activity. well.. not if you have 10k things favorited... geeze.

Comment: I think it would be easier using the API. Loop over user.me.favorites and check if deleted.